# Convert upper/lower case of vector B in respect to vector A

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have 2 data frames, for which I want to harmonize the column names. Some variables are different in respect to upper/lower case, some variables have already the same name, and some variables are unique. I want to keep the names of my first data frame, i.e. the variable names of the second data frame should be converted to the upper/lower cases of the first data frame. For that reason, the typical `toupper` or `tolower` functions do not work.

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
# Data frame A
df_a <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(5),
                   cOL2 = rnorm(5),
                   col3 = rnorm(5),
                   COL4 = rnorm(5),
                   unique_a = rnorm(5))

# Data frame B
df_b <- data.frame(COL1 = rnorm(5), # Should be converted to Col1
                   COL2 = rnorm(5), # Should be converted to cOL2
                   col3 = rnorm(5), # Should be kept as it is
                   COL4 = rnorm(5), # Should be kept as it is
                   unique_b = rnorm(5)) # Should be kept as it is

# Vectors of column names
vec_a <- colnames(df_a)
vec_b <- colnames(df_b)

# If there is a match, vec_b should be converted to vec_a
# The final result shoul look as follows:
# vec_b
# [1] "Col1"     "cOL2"     "col3"     "COL4"     "unique_b"
```

**Question: How could I convert the matching column names of data frame B to the column names of data frame A?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `plyr::mapvalues`:

```
plyr::mapvalues(x = tolower(names(df_b)), 
                from = tolower(names(df_a)), 
                to = names(df_a), 
                warn_missing = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `match` on the names that are converted to a single case and then do the assignment

```
i1 <- match(toupper(vec_a), toupper(vec_b), nomatch = 0)
i2 <- match(toupper(vec_b), toupper(vec_a), nomatch = 0)
names(df_b)[i2] <- names(df_a)[i1]
names(df_b)
#[1] "Col1"     "cOL2"     "col3"     "COL4"     "unique_b"
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thanks a lot! However, I have accepted Tino's solution, since it handles everything within one line of code.

Comment: @JoachimSchork  It's okay.  Thanks for the comments